# Jtidy - Shouldn't display encoding character(<sup>&acirc;&#132;&cent;) for TM in page source code?

Tags: tidy, htmltidy, jtidy

I'm using Jtidy to rendor news information, when news information has TM in it then page source is showing it as

'â„¢' which is invalid...

Here is my code:

InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(description.getBytes());
        OutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

```
    Tidy tidy = new Tidy(); 

    tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true);
    //tidy.setEscapeCdata(true);
    //tidy.setAsciiChars(false);
```

Any idea how to display TM in place of this encoding characters....
or how to set (ISO-8859-1) to Tidy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it by setting setInputEncoding() and setOutputEncoding() on Tidy...

Answer (score 0):

There is a HTML entity for this, not too surprisingly called `&trade;` - see e.g. http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-entities-961125

Comment: I dont find any solution in it

Comment: Pls find my code above...what to modify in that code to support html entity for TM.